# I am getting a pine script error, calculation takes too long to execute

Tags: pine-script, error-code

It only happens on some securities so expect one of the built in functions might need some error checking. I am using VWMA and was wondering if I should be error checking something before using it.
I am comparing the VWMA to the daily high for an exit strategy in the script

Since it only happens on a small percentage of securities I am concerned there may be a divide by zero or something happening in the ta.vwma function causing the long calculation.

I have never seen this before so I have no idea where to start troubleshooting.

Comment: it is usually linked to loop execution, perhaps you are running a loop to do the compare, without some script it is hard to guess whats going on

Comment: Hi John Baron   I am using a loop to fill arrays with the deltas between the VWMA and high and low for the day.

Comment: then if u r still seeing the problem i would work on that loop and determining whether u can tighten it up

Comment: Hi John Baron  It won't let me provide much of the script due to character count.                      lookBack = input.int(250, "Lookback" , step = 10)
aHigh = array.new_float(0, 0)
aLow = array.new_float(0, 0)        
for i = 0 to lookBack - 1
    array.push(aHigh , deltaHigh[i])

for i = 0 to lookBack - 1
    array.push(aLow , deltaLow[i])

Comment: i think u can update your questions or add to it, regardless, what is deltaLow[i]? what is that calc?

Comment: The deltaLow and DeltaLow calculates the percentage difference between the low of the day or high of the day compared to the VWMA of the day.  That info goes into the arrays and then the arrays are sorted from low to high. I then average the first 3 array entries for the low and the last 3 array entries for the high later in the script to determine my oversold or overbought level to compare the current delta to.

Comment: ok then i am trying to understand why these are being updated in a loop vs calculated as the time series happens and pushed into the array?

Comment: The calc for the deltaHigh and deltaLow is.... deltaHigh = (high - maV) / maV  // calculates % delta the price reaches above the VWMA
deltaLow = (low - maV) / maV    // calculates % delta the price reaches below the VWMA

Comment: As for the maV and maE   here are those calculations..... maV = ta.vwma(src, lenV)      // moving average for VWMA    
maE = ta.ema(src, lenE)       // moving average for EMA

Comment: this is done on a confirmed daily candle? when the candle closes correct?

Comment: At the close but I am not confirming a candle....  should I be using barstate.isconfirmed before I push the delta into the arrays?

Comment: put the script suggestion in the answer box

Answer (score 0):

to populate the array with delta values, without knowing how you have named your arrays, it would be similar to this:

```
maE = ta.ema(src, lenE)
deltaHigh = (high - maV) / maV
deltaLow = (low - maV) / maV

if barstate.isconfirmed
    array.push(delta_high_array, deltaHigh)
    array.push(delta_low_array, deltaLow)
```